# How to start a progress db in single user mode in unix?

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

Can you tell me the exact command to start database in single user mode? I see various answers in Kb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jensd shows how to connect to an offline database in an editor session with the ABL CONNECT statement.  Alternatively, in a proenv session (or other shell with appropriately-set DLC and PATH environment variables) you can use the pro shell script to open a database in single-user mode.

Example:
    pro /path/to/dbname

Answer (score 0):

You don't start the database in single user mode.

If you connect the database directly on disc you are connected in single user mode. If the database server is started there's no "single user mode".

Example connect:

```
CONNECT c:\temp\db.db -1.
```

-1 means single user connect.

Description here: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P17453